# How do I get rid of a zombie Celery worker?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I am running Celery with RabbitMQ backend.

Somehow I have ended up with what appears to be a zombie Celery worker. I see the worker in Flower, and in commands like `celery inspect scheduled`. But it references a PID that doesn't exist. There is no worker process. It is a big problem because Celery will delegate tasks to this worker, and they never get executed.

I believe what happened is the docker container within which this is running got shut down uncleanly. But now, even if I restart the docker container, this zombie worker always comes back. Always has the same name: `celery@0357c65d991b`.

The Celery docs say that to kill a worker you must send its process `TERM`. But I can't do that because there is no process. It's a zombie.

RabbitMQ must have a dangling reference to this worker. They only thing I could find in the RabbitMQ management interface is a queue named `celery@0357c65d991b.celery.pidbox`. I deleted this queue, but it simply reappeared a few seconds later.

Can anyone give me a pointer on where to look to get rid of this thing?